# Android play console: internal testing version, close testing ? how does it works?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, google-play-internal-testing

I already have a production app on play store,
now I have uploaded the next release version on internal testing track,
I have created a mailing list with team testers, but now all the tester of my team see the test version and they cannot choose between production version and test version. Is there a way to choose between the two version ?

How can the tester chooses between production app and the testing version ?

Moreover I'm wondering which is the difference between Android play console internal testing and closed testing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

End users (or testers) cannot choose which version they want, they will always receive the APK/AAB with the highest versionCode that they are eligible for.

If users receive the APK from a testing track and want to go back to the production one, they have to opt out of the testing then reinstall the app (since Android will never downgrade an app) or wait for the next production push.