# Google Play Console App Inactive but Available to internal testers

Tags: android, google-play-console

I am trying to send out an android app to my internal testers.

I added them to the mailing list. Checked the mailing list. I saved all the details. I sent out the Opt-in URL. My tester went to Google Play settings and clicked on Play version 7 times and toggled internal testers. They follow the URL and are not able to see the app.

My app on google play console shows this. It's confusing messaging.

In Internal Testing... Notice it says "Track summary INACTIVE" and also below "Releases AVAILABLE TO INTERNAL TESTERS"

[image: confusing inactive available to internal testers]

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

> My tester went to Google Play settings and clicked on Play version 7
> times

I can't get what this (= *7 times*) means.

I opened an invitation url on my Android phone tagged to the invited Google account. Then I just clicked once to accept invitation like this image:

[image: screenshot]

Lastly, I opened Google Play with **download it on Google Play** link to install the app.

### Update

On my Google Play console, it has a version code (and a version name). Make sure you set your app `versionCode` (and `versionName`) in `build.gradle`.

[image: Google Play console]

Comment: I updated my post. Notice in Internal testing... it says "Track summary INACTIVE" and also below "Releases AVAILABLE TO INTERNAL TESTERS". Do you also have that in the google play console?

Comment: @Slackware I see. I noticed a difference on Google Play console between mine and yours, mine has a version code while yours not.

Comment: I see what you are talking about. I tried to replicate. Click on "Create a Release", "App Bundles > Add from library", Chose an aab file, then it asks for input "Release Details > Release Name" and that Release name contains a default name that is the version. That's why yours is the version. I changed my release name to a specific name

Comment: I think it's interesting to note. If I go to Setup > Advanced Settings > App availability > App availability. I checked "Unpublished". That might be the issue. I did that because I accidentally sent a release to production and wanted to remove it. I don't know how to un-publish in production...

Comment: @Slackware FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65737106/3501958 *End users (or testers) cannot choose which version they want, they will always receive the APK/AAB with the highest versionCode that they are eligible for.* So, regardless the former was unpublished or not, you may set a larger number as `versionCode` for the latter test release.

Comment: I was able to go to Advanced Settings and set the setting to "Published". I needed to make sure my app was available in the country of my testers